# How to check if a Form has a required field on one of its control

Tags: angular, angular2-forms, angular2-formbuilder, typescript2.1

I have the following form

```
  ethnicGroup: AbstractControl;
  form: FormGroup;
  type: AbstractControl;

constructor(
      private _fb: FormBuilder) {

    this.form = this._fb.group(
        {
          'type': [ '',  ],
          'ethnicGroup': [ '',  ]
        } );

    this.type = this.form.controls[ 'type' ];
    this.ethnicGroup = this.form.controls[ 'ethnicGroup' ]
  }
```

Is there a way to check if a form has a required field on one of its control?

Thanks

Comment: HI, you want a change to those two values optional to  required fields?

Answer (score 0):

You can check this by printing the form object in your console.

Comment: I was thinking in a programmatic sense ie check if the control is required and then do something if it is true or false.